# What does it mean to "apply a global class name"?

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to build my interface using Material-UI (current version is 3.1.2.)

A while ago when I was using Bootstrap4, I added `style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%"` to my `head` tag to always show a scrollbar to stop the app from jumping around when the page content grew longer than the screen.

Now that I'm trying to use Material-UI, the overflow setting seems to cause problems when combined with Material-UI's popup components (popper, menu, etc.)

I read in the FAQ that this is a known issue with a workaround: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-do-the-fixed-positioned-elements-move-when-a-modal-is-opened-

But I'm not sure what that's telling me to do.
What is implied by the phrase "apply a global class" in the following?

> "apply a global .mui-fixed class name ... to handle those elements."

Where do they intend that `mui-fixed` would be added - to every component in my app?  To the anchor of the menu/popper?  Or do they mean that I'm supposed to apply it "globally" (ie. high up in the React page component hierarchy somehwere?)

In the meantime, as a workaround, I've just removed the overflow styling from my `html` element.
The app content still jumps about when the content grows/shrinks across page size, but it seems less ugly than when I was using Bootstrap.

---

I tried adding the `mui-fixed` class to my body, so when the app starts, it looks like:

```
<body style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%" class="mui-fixed">
```

So when the page is short, there is a disabled scrollbar.  If the page grows, the scrollbar becomes enabled.

Then, while the menu popup is displayed, Material-UI changes it to this:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; padding-right: 17px;" class="mui-fixed">
```

Which looks fine, regardless of the content's length.  But then when the menu is dismissed, Material-UI changes the body element to:

```
<body style="height: 100%; padding-right: 0px;" class="mui-fixed">
```

The overflow style is gone and this results in the scrollbar being removed entirely if the page content is shorter than the window - so the page content "jumps" across to fill the space from the missing scrollbar.

Comment: You need to apply `mui-fixed` class to the element with `position:fixed` that you don't want moving when opening the modal (typically a `<header>` or a `<footer>`). Inspect the `<header>` here and watch how it doesn't move when opening the modal.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to provide [the link](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/). Cheers!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I've added `classname="mui-header"` to my AppBar and saw the `mui-header` class in the inspector, but it had no effect on the behaviour of the page.

Comment: Why would adding `mui-header` class have any effect, @Shorn? I'm not able to find anything related to it in M-UI documentation. Where did you come up with that class name from?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  Typo.  It was "mui-fixed" I actually added to the AppBar.

Comment: Re-reading your comment though, why do you talk about a `position:fixed` element? My AppBar is `position:static`.  And it's not just the AppBar that's affected, it's the whole page.

Comment: I talk about a `position:fixed` element because that's what `mui-fixed` was designed for. To keep fixed top/bottom bars in place when the modal open/closes.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Oh.  I get why you were talking about `position:fixed` now.  The FAQ entry is actually only for "fixed positioned" elements - I guess I glossed over that when I was looking for a solution for my problem.  The whole question is wrong I guess.

Comment: Your question is not wrong. However, `.mui-fixed` was not designed for this purpose and it won't help you keep the `<body>` element unchanged when the modal opens.

Comment: Looking closer at what's happening on M-UI's website to the `<body>` element: they add `overflow:hidden;padding-right:17px;` to `<body>` when the modal opens, in desktop Chrome. The padding is not added to browsers with a floating scrollbar, such as FF, or when the `<body>` element doesn't need scrolling.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yeah, I've raised an issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13235.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think you'll get much joy from that issue. It's clearly not a M-UI problem. It's a "Chrome on desktop" problem. Some browsers decided to go with scrollbars only shown when scrolling or when hovered (but this disables pointer events over that portion of the page - which in some cases might be important). Others went with shrinking the page by the width of the scrollbar. It's a complex problem and there's no perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is for scrollbar if I got it correct, then it would be apply "globally" one time.

Comment: globally one time where?

Comment: you can apply it in body tag or any parent container which is containing you full page.

Comment: adding `class="mui-fixed" to the body tag has no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

in your styles.ts you can add:

```
    '@global': {
      '.mui-fixed': {
        // something here
      },
    },
```

and it will apply globally!